# What makes the below question off-topic and ideally which site should this be migrated to..?

Tags: discussion

Consider:

[What should I use as a base for my wall mounted PC case?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/what-should-i-use-as-a-base-for-my-wall-mounted-pc-case)

Looking at the 'Note, the following are considered off-topic:' section, it is a Hobby project.
But as per this section: 'We welcome these topics:' it does seem to fit in on this site:

1. Questions you would typically ask a home contractor. [No, well maybe]
2. Which tools and materials to use for a specific task. **[Yes]**
3. Best practices for a specific task. **[Yes]**
4. Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home. [No]
5. National building codes (of any country). [Nope]
6. Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances. [No]
7. Carpentry and woodworking. **[Yes]**

I feel there is a need for a site dedicated to all other DIY projects that include hobby projects too.

See here: [DIY-projects](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48770/diy-projects)

Comment: Number 2 should probably be "*Which tools and materials to use for a specific **home improvement** task*", as well as number 3 "*Best practices for a specific **home Improvement** task*". So in your case, only number 7 would apply, and only if you chose to use wood.

Comment: +1 Yup.. Similarly #3 should be more specific too.

Comment: @Tester101 could you suggest other projects besides Home-Improvement and hobby projects that would be a part of [DIY-projects](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48770/diy-projects). Of course hobby projects would benefit from the knowledge generated on this site but would cover a broader area of construction materials..

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there isn't a site to migrate it to, so an area51 proposal is the best option. There was an attempt in the past to have a [personal manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing) site, but that failed. You may want to consider how much of the maker community you can include with your proposal since they would be helpful in getting your site off the ground.

As for why it's off topic here, getting into hobby projects gets out of the expertise of this community and can quickly become a very broad and ambiguous subject. Personally, I tend to watch Mike Holmes and This Old House, but I don't participate in the local hacker space, these are two distinct communities to me. In the past, there have been attempts to create sites around personal electronics that failed because they became very broad with too few people that could answer the questions. The lesson there is that we don't want a site that's so broad that anyone can ask a question, but no one is around to answer it. The model adopted by SE is sites that have a well defined scope that can attract a core group able the answer the questions. Unfortunately, this means that good questions don't always have a place where they can be asked.

Comment: Good points @BMitch!Thanks

Comment: Although [Personal Manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing) failed,we did start a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication?referrer=HAU0BHc85WMAKpA7nTzd4Q2) to [reboot it](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/5726/40660)